Got numpy array shape as (32, 32, 4) instead of (32, 32, 3) : Subsampling CIFAR 10 dataset
I want to get image folders according to 10 classes.Im a beginner in deep learning and data science. Before transforming to images from data_batches, i've checked the shape of first numpy array(image). I got (32, 32, 3). After transforming to images, i got shape as (32, 32, 4).
Thankyou.
part 1: Before transforming:
#Plot the Image using Matplotlib
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = train_data[1][0]   #2nd sample, image
class_name = class_names[train_data[1][1]]
plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title(class_name)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

img_as_array = np.asarray(image)
img_as_array.shape

output : (32, 32, 3)
part 2: While transforming :

## Create labels directories in data_dir and save their images from batches.
import os
import numpy as np
import pickle
from tqdm import tqdm

# Function to load CIFAR-10 batch file
def unpickle(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict

# Create directories for each class
def create_class_directories(data_dir, label_names):
    # Create data directory if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
        os.makedirs(data_dir)

    for label_name in label_names:
        directory = os.path.join(data_dir, label_name)
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)

# Save images to their respective class directories
def save_images_to_directories(data, labels, label_names, data_dir):
    for image, label in tqdm(zip(data, labels), total=len(data)):
        label_name = label_names[label]
        directory = os.path.join(data_dir, label_name)
        filename = os.path.join(directory, f'image_{label}_{np.random.randint(0, 1e6)}.png')
        image = image.reshape((3, 32, 32)).transpose((1, 2, 0))  # Reshape image data
        plt.imsave(filename, image)

# Path to CIFAR-10 dataset files
data_dir = "/content/data/cifar-10-batches-py"  # Changed to "data"
label_names = ["airplane", "automobiles", "bird", "cat", "deer", "dog", "frog", "horse", "ship", "truck"]

# Load and organize data
create_class_directories(data_dir, label_names)

# Load training data batches
for i in range(1, 6):
    batch = unpickle(os.path.join(data_dir, f"data_batch_{i}"))
    save_images_to_directories(batch[b'data'], batch[b'labels'], label_names, data_dir)

# Load test data batch
test_batch = unpickle(os.path.join(data_dir, "test_batch"))
save_images_to_directories(test_batch[b'data'], test_batch[b'labels'], label_names, data_dir)


part 3: Image paths after above transformation
random_image_path = random.choice(image_path_list)

img = Image.open(random_image_path)

img_as_array = np.asarray(img)
img_as_array.shape

output: (32, 32, 4)

I expected (32, 32, 3). Can you please help?
Thankyou
your text
